# How to log in to admin account from a non-admin account?

Tags: sudo, privileges, adduser

I have an admin account with `sudo` privilege. I have created a new user but haven't given a `sudo` privilege to it. Then I logged in as that new user:

```
sudo -i -u foo_user
```

Now I want to get back to my admin account but cannot do the same thing and get an error:

```
foo_user@ubuntu:~$ sudo -i -u admin1
[sudo] password for foo_user: 
foo_user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

So how is it possible to get back to my admin account now?

Answer (score 3):

`exit` is the command you are looking for.

It will exit the current user's shell session and return to its parent, which in this case is the session of the admin user.

Answer (score 3):

simply use `su`. This would be like the following

```
su admin1
Password:
```

Give the correct password of admin1. Done. To know more about `-i` option that you are using see the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html)

```
-i [command]
               The -i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell
               specified by the password database entry of the target user
               as a login shell.
```

Answer (score 1):

use `su` command to do this.

using `man su` command you can get more detail.

```
su admin1
```

Then type your admin account password.